# Build and Publish docker images to Nexus3

Tags: docker, jenkins, maven-3, nexus3, docker-maven-plugin

New to nexus.. We are trying to automate build process (Build docker images and publish them to Nexus3 repository).. My requirement is, I have an image built using `docker build -t <imagename>:<version> .` now I want to publish this docker image to nexus repo using Jenkins.

I have a nexus repo and Jenkins Job is configured with docker-maven plugin also I have provided `docker:push` maven target.. Not sure how to push now? Do I need to use shell script with `docker push <imagename>:<version>` or what steps I have to mention in Jenkins CI job.

Please help me..

Answer (score 2):

From the question it is not clear whether you have set up Nexus Docker Registry or Nexus Maven Repository. You wrote about "Nexus Repo", which implies Nexus Maven Repo.

#### If you mean Nexus Maven Repository...

Docker stores images into a Docker server. It connects to it using it's own protocol. Nexus is a different paradigm and not compatible as is.

Docker Maven Plugin's `push` goal pushes to a remote Docker repository, e.g. [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/), or GitLab. That is different from "deploying" Maven artifacts to Nexus.

Docker allows to get an image in a form of a `.tar` file using `docker load`.
Maybe someone created some kind of "wagon", a thing that would to allow maven to "resolve" these files which you would declare as dependencies.
But the whole idea is probably not really advisable following. As I said, Maven and Docker's approaches are different.

**Edit:** So it turns out that [somebody did](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/docker-registry) - and it was the creators of Nexus.
As pointed out by @masseyb. But after quick reading, it turns out that it's just a normal Docker registry, just branded and and bundled with Nexus. I assume that the poster asked about how to use Nexus **Maven** repository to store Docker images.

#### If you have the **Nexus Docker registry**...

then you need to:

- [Set up D-M-P](https://dmp.fabric8.io/#pull-vs-push-authentication), using the credentials set up in Nexus.
  I think you can also `docker login` to that; before running Maven.
- Set the repository ID as prefix in `<name>` of the `<image>`.
- The `push` goal will then push to that repository.

This [article about using multiple registries](https://ro14nd.de/registry-magic-with-dmp) may come handy, too.

Comment: Downvoted because nexus can be configured as a [docker registry](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/docker-registry).

Comment: OP can create a hosted docker repository in nexus (eventually add a reverse proxy in front of it), tag the images with the server name (needs to be resolved) and use the docker:push maven target to push the images. Upvoted edited answer.

Comment: From the question it is not clear that the OP uses Nexus Docker Registry. He writes about Nexus Repo, which implies Nexus Maven Repo.

Comment: I agree, my understanding ref. the mention of “I have also provided [docker:push](http://dmp.fabric8.io/#docker:push) maven target” is that OP is trying to push the images to his own docker registry hosted in nexus.

Comment: A side note that `nexus3` does a lot tbh (ref. your mention "which implies Nexus Maven Repo"). We use it as our `docker` hosted (internal) registry and proxy, `pypi`, `apt`, `npm`, ...

Comment: I understand, we also use it as storage for all kinds of files, and it is really cool. But for Docker images, the standard Nexus Maven approach with G:A:V is not applicable well, IMHO.